# @MapKeyColumn(name="XXX") is not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I am using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate 4.x. I found @MakKeyColumn is not woking.

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "cub_id")
    private Map<String, Employee> employeesByCubicle = new HashMap<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Map<String, Employee> getEmployeesByCubicle() {
        return employeesByCubicle;
    }

    public void setEmployeesByCubicle(Map<String, Employee> employeesByCubicle) {
        this.employeesByCubicle = employeesByCubicle;
    }
}
```

if the above code is executed, i can see following error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "cub_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (2, xxxxxx, null, null).
```

But, if I omit `@MapKeyColumn`, it's working. Can anyone let me know why it's not working when using `@MapKeyColumn`

Thanks for response in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try defining MapKeyColumn as nullable:

```
@MapKeyColumn(name = "cub_id", nullable = true)
```

The default value for nullable property is 'false'.

Comment: Thanks for response. your answer is correct. it's working. But, Map Key is always used when we use Map Object. so `@MapKeyColumn` needs to be not null. it's strange that if it's just only nullable, working well.

Comment: This is a problem in your database and it has nothing to do with the problem and the solution. If the answer is correct, please mark it as one, so other people can use it.